# How to reach ToolStripMenu items of the contextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip, toolstripitem

I am new at C#. I have added a contextMenuStrip in the desing part, and also I added 4 different ToolStriptItem. Three of them are ToolStriptMenuItem, named like successToolStripMenuItem etc. , and one of them is ToolStripTextBox.

What I want is to reach all members of contextMenuStrip. Is there any way to put all items into an array?

I know there is a code like that:

```
ToolStripItem[] tsi = contextMenuStrip.Items.Find("successToolStripMenuItem", true);
```

This code is not handy, because only returns 1 member, however I want to get all four elements into the array. That's why I can easily reach them and use them. If my only option is using the code above, I will need to create three more ToolStripItem array, which will have only one member either. This did not seem much practical solution to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are looking for is here:

```
ToolStripItem[] tsi = new ToolStripItem[] { successToolStripMenuItem,
                                            successToolStripTextBox };
```

The other way to do this, without having to manually add the items, is shown below:

```
ToolStripItem[] tsi = new ToolStripItem[contextMenuStrip.Items.Count];
contextMenuStrip.Items.CopyTo(tsi, 0);
```

But just so you know, `contextMenuStrip.Items` is a `Collection` meaning you can address the items in that collection just like you would for an array. For example:

```
contextMenuStrip.Items[0]
```